# R: How to allow axis scales but not tick mark count to vary by facet in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Many ggplot users often want plots with multiple facets in which a scale is allowed to vary freely because the range of values for a given facet may differ substantially across the values of the faceting variable.

However, while the `scale` argument of `facet_grid()` allows each facet to have its own scale, it also allow each facet to have its own number of axis tick marks. Is there a way to hold constant the axis tick mark count across facets while letting the values of the marks vary?

Comment: This seems an under specified request. There are algorithms for “pretty” choices for axis ticks. You should do a bit of searching.

Comment: I don't think so, unless you want to play with extending the limits of axes on facets. The default break calculation is done by `scales::extended_breaks()` for each facet individually. It makes an attempt at choosing the breaks according to the number of breaks you want, but it also tries to optimise for simplicity, coverage, density and legibility. That's why you don't always see 5 breaks, which is the default.